# Count True/False occurences across dataframe (columns & rows)

Tags: python, pandas

I try to find the sum of all "True" occurences in a dataframe

df

```
A   B     C   D 
1 True False True False
2 False False False True
3 True True False True
4 True False False True
```

Result showed by 8

I tried

```
condition_total = df[df.values = True].counts()
```

I find solutions for columns but not for the whole dataframe

Comment: use sum twice `df.sum().sum()` , first one gives sum for each series, next gives sum for the returned series

Comment: `np.sum` flattens by default so you can check your equality against the array `(df.to_numpy() == 'your_value').sum()`

Comment: Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df == something` to get a matrix of which values are equal to the data you're looking for. You can then count the results per row using `.sum()` and then sum up the column using `.sum()` again.

The following code gives 9 using `== False` and 7 using `== True`.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"A": [True, False, True, True], 
     "B": [True, False, False, False], 
     "C": [True, False, False, False],
     "D": [False, True, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
condition_total = (df == False).sum().sum()
print(condition_total)
```

The comparison with `== True` is redundant, so it can just be `df.sum().sum()`.